# commit changed in DataGridView when selection changed in ComboBox

Tags: datagridview, combobox, focus

How can I force the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event to be raised (and have the changed acutally committed to the `DataGridViewCell.Value` property) as soon as the `ComboBox` editing control in a cell changed its selection? By default the event is only raised after the cell with the ComboBox loses focus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it doing this:

```
    myDataGridView.EditingControlShowing += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(myDataGridView_EditingControlShowing);

    private void myDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
        {
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
            cmb.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cmb_SelectionChangeCommitted);
            cmb.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(cmb_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        }
    }

    void cmb_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvPresupuesto.CurrentCell.Value = ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)sender).EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Allthough I have not tried this approach (using the the `EditingControlFormattedValue` property) and can not confirm that it acutally works, it sure looks right and less noise than my approach. So I am accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Worked for me although I changed `EditingControlFormattedValue` to `SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing it this way. I have no idea if that is the "preferred" way or if it will yield any side effects later, but for now it seems to work:

```
this.gridView.EditingControlShowing += this.GridViewOnEditingControlShowing;

private void GridViewOnEditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cellComboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cellComboBox != null)
    {
        // make sure the handler doen't get registered twice
        cellComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted -= this.CellComboBoxOnelectionChangeCommitted;
        cellComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += this.CellComboBoxOnelectionChangeCommitted;
    }
}

private void CellComboBoxOnelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboBox = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if (sender == null)
    {
        return;
    }     
    if (comboBox.SelectedValue == null)
    {
        return;
    }    
    if (this.gridView.CurrentCell.Value == comboBox.SelectedValue)
    {
        return;
    }    
    this.gridView.CurrentCell.Value = comboBox.SelectedValue;        
}
```

Comment: the combox value needs to be selected twice for the first time to select an item

Answer (score 0):

The change in value of the combobox is actually a Editing control associated with the Grid.
So to initiate anything you will have to add those in the EditingControlShowing Event of the DataGrid for that particular column

```
private void dg_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  if (dg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
  {
    ComboBox cmbox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    cmbox.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(cmbox_SelectedValueChanged);
  }
}
```

you can call the cell value changed event in the selected cvalue changed event of the Combobox

Comment: This approach doesn't work, because the value has not yet been committed to the underlying `DataGridViewCell.Value` and in the EventHandler of `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` I have no way of finding out what the new value is. I need to find a way to force the datagrid itself to commit the changes to the cell and raise the `CellValueChanged` event.

Comment: In that case you may trigger TAB event using SendKeys.Send("{TAB}"); in combobox event handler forcing the cell to lose focus, eventually triggering the CellValueChanged for the grid

Comment: That's also not ideal because the current cell will lose focus. This should not happen in my scenario.